# Xamarin iPhone deploy with Xcode won't show it connected

Tags: xcode, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My iPhone is connected to the mac (Can be seen under System Information>USB>iPhone) but Xcode does not let me use the iPhone and it says at the app scheme "No devices connected to My Mac."
I will be really happy if someone will be able to help me with it, it's my Matriculation Project.

[image]

Comment: 1.Check if your phone trust the Mac. 2.Close all and proceed again.

Comment: What do you mean by if my iPhone's trusted? How can I verify?

Comment: When you connect your iPhone, the phone will automatically prompt you to allow it.

Comment: Oh yes, I've done it.
The thing is that the Mac recognize my iPhone but Xcode does not :(

Comment: Try to update ios or XCode.

Comment: Both are up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by reinstalling mac and Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Xcode -> In a terminal window enter `sudo pkill usbmuxd` -> Restart Xcode.
2. If the first method cannot be solved, try to check the development target setting of Xcode.